# Tic Tac Toe Program help

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I am not sure how to proceed from what I have already: I am having trouble getting my array to work and I am also having trouble with my chart reseting everytime i re-run the program. It does not save my X's and O's but restarts into the blank chart. Any hint will be helpful. Thanks

```
/**
Lab 4 - Due 7/22/2010.

Convert Lab 3 to a class

1. Implement displayBoard to display Tic Tac Toe board.
2. Prompt User for a box on the board to select, i.e. a number between 1 and 9 with 1 being the upper left corner.

use cin.get(box) to get the box number and isdigit to verify it is a
number;
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
7 | 8 | 9
If the box is available put the appropriate X or O in there and switch players, i.e. X becomes O and vice versa.
If the box is NOT available warn the user and get another box until they select a valid open box.

3. After all spots have been select Display "Game Over!";
4. Write a main function to use the TicTacToe class and test all of the above functionality.

**/


#include <iostream>

#include <limits>

using namespace std;


class TicTacToe {
public:
    void displayBoard();
    void getMove();
    void playGame();
private:
    char board[9];
    char player; // Switch after each move.
};

int main ()
{
    TicTacToe ttt;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        ttt.playGame();
    }
}

void TicTacToe::playGame()
{
    displayBoard();


    getMove();    

    // Your implementation here...
}

void TicTacToe::displayBoard()
{
    // Your implementation here...

    bool firstMove = true;
    if (firstMove  == true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board[i] = i + 1;
        }

    }

    firstMove == false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        if ( (i+1) % 3 == 0 )
        {
            cout << board[i] << endl;
        }
        else 
        {

            cout << board[i] << " | ";
        }
    }
}

void TicTacToe::getMove()
{
    if (player == 'X') { 
        player = 'O';
    }
    else {
        player = 'X';
    }

    cout << player << " ";
    cout << "Enter Box: ";
    char c;


    bool move;
    move = true;

    do {
        cin.get(c);
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
        if (c > '9' || c < '0')
            // error message
            cout << "please enter a number 1-9" << endl;

        int number = c - '0';

        cout << "your number is " << number << endl;
        // Your implementation here...

        if (c == '1' && board[0] == '1') {
            board[0] = player;

            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '2' && board[1] == '2')
        {
            board[1] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '3' && board[2] == '3')
        {
            board[2] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '4' && board[3] == '4')
        {
            board[3] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '5' && board[4] == '5')
        {
            board[4] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '6' && board[5] == '6')
        {
            board[5] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '7' && board[6] == '7')
        {
            board[6] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '8' && board[7] == '8')
        {
            board[7] = player;
            move = false;
        }
        else if(c == '9' && board[8] == '9')
        {
            board[8] = player;
            move = false;
        }

    } while (!move);     
}
```

@Bunnit From your advice i was able to change it up. Now my only problem is replacing each box with an X or O it doesnt seem like my if and else if are working.

Comment: This question appears every 2-3 days, It seems that some university has given a homework for this.

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You appear to be about a week late...

Comment: Every time i run the program it seems like my arrays are not being saved. It prints blank spaces and | lines only. I tried using char board = { '1', '2', '3',} and so on but that does not work. It is not a week late. This is just a summer programming class im taking to improve my work chances.

Comment: @Zach: A week and a year late.

Comment: Don't completely remove your question and replace it by a new one. Like this the answers won't make any sense anymore for any future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the DisplayBoard function to display your board?

```
    bool firstMove = true;
    if (firstMove  == true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            board[i] = i + 1;
        }

    }
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here but firstMove will always be true so your board will be getting reset everytime this is called.Also below this:

`firstMove == false;`

this line has no effect, to set firstMove to false use `firstMove = false;` though the if statement above will still be called each time as firstMove is set to true everytime the function is called, if you only want to set firstMove to true on the first call to DisplayBoard you could use a static variable: 
`static firstMove == true;`.

### Edit

It also looks like the you have confused chars with ints, in DisplayBoard you set each board tile to be equal to it's corresponding number(the for statement above), but when you check this in the getMove function you use the character equivalents:`if (c == '1' && board[0] == '1')`.  1!='1'.  Since it is homework I'll leave it to you to look up an ascii chart to find out what it does equal.

Comment: ahh very helpful!!! But I am still have trouble displaying the numbers on the board. It just does not show despite assigning each one in board[i] using for.

Comment: I see!! But for some reason i cannot get my display board to show the numbers o.o I only get spaces and | lines. unless i do char board [9] = { '1', '2'} That is the only time the numbers would show up on the board. sorry I am kind of noob in programming. You have helped me enough.

Answer (score 0):

When a program ends, all of its memory is reclaimed by the operating system so that it can be used by other programs. All values in variables and arrays are lost when a program ends.

If you want to maintain some persistent state until the next time the program is run, you need to save your variables/arrays to some storage medium like a file or a database. When the program is later started, you load those variables/arrays back from the storage medium.

If they didn't teach you how to read/write files yet, then I doubt they expect your game board to be restored to it's previous state every time your program starts.

Comment: that is true but I am having a hard time maintain the X's and O's in each box without them turning back to 1 2 3 boxes

Answer (score 0):

Rather than filling the board with numbers and then overwriting with X's and O,s you should just take an input in an integer format. That might help with the overwriting problem. Also, I don't know if you've covered 2D Arrays or not, but it would help your programming and logical thought process a bit more if you used them.

Comment: P.S try implementing a computer vs. Player mode to test your programming skills.